# Compare tiny capacitance using comparator

Tags: capacitor, comparator, voltage-measurement

I want to compare the capacitance of two tiny capacitors at around 10^-15 F each. One will change compared to the other by at maximum factor 3. I need to measure the relative difference between them to an accuracy of around 1%.
My idea is to connect them in series to form a ”voltage divider” and then connect the middle of them to a comparator which can then compare the voltage between the capacitors to some external reference voltage.

However, I have no experience with comparators or exactly how they work. Would the comparator try to draw a current from the capacitors it was comparing (and thus not work since there’s basically no charge to draw)?
What should I look for when buying a comparator for this application?

If this is simply not possible, how else might I accuratley (and cheaply) compare the values of these two capacirors?
Note, not looking for some expensive high tech solution here, looking for something which can be done at home by an amature.

Comment: Are you sure of the value?   Those are truly tiny capacitors, likely you will incur many orders more capacitance just connecting them to something.  Single digit picofarads can be measured by timing their charge through a megaohm resistor, something like looking at phase shift in an extremely high frequency RF system might work for you, for example if you could toggle rapidly between two paths you might induce some modulation detectable with an FM (or really PM) receiver.  But it's going to be very tricky.  Where does this requirement come from?

Comment: You are posing a very difficult problem.  However you need to provide more information to allow the possibility of a solution.  For example, how close in value are these 2 capacitors? Do you need to measure the difference (in which case to what accuracy and resolution?), or just determine which one is greater? Are the capacitors electrically separate or do they share a common terminal?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I want to measure the volume of plastic filament entering a 3D printer to a high degree of accoracy, running the fillament though a capacitor allows me to (in theory) calculate the cross section area of the filament (or rather the volume of a small lenght of it). The reason for the tiny capacitance is the large distance between the ”plates” (1.75mm) and the very small area I am interested in.

Comment: Your PCB's parasitic capacitances would dwarf what you are trying to measure

Comment: Consider something like a rotary encoder with an arm holding a follower wipe or wheel or even something optical looking at the filament under carefully arranged lighting.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The idea of using capacitance was to get the cross section area easily/cheaply. An arm/light would only give the thickness of the filament at a certain point (the filament doesn’t have to be perfectly circular). But if comparing capacitances this small doesn’t work then I guess I have to resort to some other method. Pressure changes looks promising :)

Comment: Better (probably) would be to propose a "how do I do what I want to do" question. By all means suggest ideas that you have re solutions - but hiding the real question deep in the comments is liable to not be the best approach.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I did get my question answered, I wanted to find out if it would be possible to measure such tiny capacitances without any huge lab equipment. Had I asked "How do I measure the diameter of a wire very precisely" people would have talked about the standard ways of doing it with light or some physical sensor, I wanted to know if it was possible using capacitances and that's why I didn't mention that I was "simply" trying to measure the diameter (cross sectional area) of a wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest general purpose electronic capacitor in the world is 0.1pF. \$=10^{-13}~F\$

Your requirement so far does not have any merit as \$
10^{-15}~F\$ is only 1% of this.

Unless you can define your dielectric, conductor geometry and purpose, nothing close to what you suggest is suitable.

You are asking how to measure capacitance less than two 1mm square pads separated by 1 meter.

try something else.

Comment: I’m not actually trying to measure the capacitance itself, only the relative difference between the two tiny capacitors. What the actuall value is doesn’t matter to me, though it would still require extreme resolution so it might not make a difference, but generally comparing two capacitors is much easier than measuring the value, right?

Comment: @BeaconofWierd - Tony's example is excellent. (I won't even check if he's correct - he usually is :-) ). With 2 x 1 mm^2 pads at one meter it would be easier to tell if the user was or wasn't in the room, and maybe if they were standing on one leg :-(.

Comment: I once tested tested a new high Z ESD meter by standing on 1 leg on a nylon carpet and by changing my body C I could generate 200V = Q/C . amazing  Sorry BoW but 1pF is about the limit for a hobbiest and thats less than a low C input comparator. But if you use that on a XTAL OSC. you can expect 200 ppm /10 pf. SO do the math on f resolution. in ppm  . Can you measure this?

Comment: What about voltage multipliers? The time they take to charge up the voltage is dependent highly upon the capacitance of the first capacitor in the chain, right?
I played around some in a circuit simulator, using 0.04pF and a 16MHz square wave and charging for 20 us the voltage rose to 370m V while if I used 0.03pF it reached only 300 mV. That's a very measurable difference. I even included stray capacitance in the model, no difference.